# R - Sorting and Sub-setting Maximum Values within Columns

Tags: sorting, r, subset

I am trying to iteratively sort data within columns to extract N maximum values.

My data is set up with the first and second columns containing occupation titles and codes, and all of the rest of the columns containing comparative values (in this case location quotients that had to be previously calculated for each city) for those occupations for various cities:

```
    *occ_code  city1  ...   city300*
     occ1      5      ...    7
     occ2      20     ...   22
     .         .       .     .
     .         .       .     .
     occ800    20     ...   25
```

For each city I want to sort by the maximum values, select a subset of those maximum values  matched by their respective occupations titles and titles. I thought it would be relatively trivial but...

*edit for clarification:* I want end to with a sorted subset of the data for analysis.

```
     occ_code   city1
     occ200     10
     occ90      8
     occ20      2
     occ95      1.5
```

At the same time I want to be able to repeat the sort column-wise (so I've tried lots of order commands through calling columns directly: data[,2]; just to be able to run the same analysis functions over the entire dataset.

I've been messing with plyr for the past 3 days and I feel like the setup of my dataset is just not conducive to how plyer was meant to be used.

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit? It would help to give us an example with a smaller data frame as input and an example of the output you'd like to extract.

Comment: yeah, it's hard to figure out what you want here.

Comment: At first, I want to get a subset with two columns of data: a list of the 10 largest values of column "city1", matched with their respective "occ_codes", (from the first column). 

This would be a simple enough sort in say excel, only I would need to repeat the operation 300 times * 10 years of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your desired output is according to your example snippit. Here's how you could get a data frame like that for every city using `plyr` and `reshape`

```
#using the same df from nico's answer
library(reshape)
df.m <- melt(df, id = 1)
a.cities <- cast(df.m, codes ~ . | variable)

library(plyr)
a.cities.max <- aaply(a.cities, 1, function(x) arrange(x, desc(`(all)`))[1:4,])
```

Now, `a.cities.max` is an array of data frames, with the 4 largest values for each city in each data frame. To get one of these data frames, you can index it with

```
a.cities.max$X13
```

I don't know exactly what you'll be doing with this data, but you might want it back in data frame format.

```
df.cities.max <- adply(a.cities.max, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use `order` with `ddply` from the package `plyr`

```
> library(plyr)
> d<-data.frame(occu=rep(letters[1:5],2),city=rep(c('A','B'),each=5),val=1:10)
> ddply(d,.(city),function(x) x[order(x$val,decreasing=TRUE)[1:3],])
```

`order` can sort on multiple columns if you want that.

Answer (score 0):

This will output the max for each city. Similar results can be obtained using `sort` or `order`

```
# Generate some fake data
codes <- paste("Code", 1:100, sep="")
values <- matrix(0, ncol=20, nrow=100)
for (i in 1:20)
    values[,i] <- sample(0:100, 100, replace=T)

df <- data.frame(codes, values)

names(df) <- c("Code", paste("City", 1:20, sep=""))

# Now for each city we get the maximum
maxval <- apply(df[2:21], 2, which.max)
# Output the max for each city
print(cbind(paste("City", 1:20), codes[maxval]))
```